# Convert From FetchRequest Array To NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My app currently fetches data on routineViewController's launch and loads it into eventsArray.  I was encouraged to try using a NSFetchedResultsController instead.

I'm currently going through the Apple docs to learn more about it but in the meantime if anyone could help me start this conversion process, that would be great.

I added all the fetchresultscontroller code from the apple template but need help combing my addEvent method and the fetchresultcontroller's insertnewobject method.  Or do I keep both?

```
@implementation RoutineTableViewController

@synthesize routineTableView;
@synthesize eventsArray;
@synthesize entered;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(CurlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    }

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    [self setEventsArray:mutableFetchResults];
    [mutableFetchResults release];
    [request release];

    UIBarButtonItem * addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showPrompt)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:addButton];
    [addButton release];

    UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(toggleEdit)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;
    [editButton release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.eventsArray = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

-(void)toggleEdit
{
    [self.routineTableView setEditing: !self.routineTableView.editing animated:YES];

    if (self.routineTableView.editing)
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
    else
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [managedObjectContext release];
    [eventsArray release];
    [entered release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Add an event

-(void)addEvent
{    
    Routine *routine = (Routine *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    routine.name=entered;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", error);

    [eventsArray addObject:routine];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    [self.routineTableView reloadData];

    NSInteger lastSection = [self.routineTableView numberOfSections] -1;


    [self.routineTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.routineTableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSection]-1 inSection:lastSection] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}

-(void)showPrompt
{
    AlertPrompt *prompt = [AlertPrompt alloc];
    prompt = [prompt initWithTitle:@"Add Workout Day" message:@"\n \n Please enter title for workout day" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" okButtonTitle:@"Add"];
    [prompt show];
    [prompt release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
    {
        entered = [(AlertPrompt *)alertView enteredText];

        if(eventsArray && entered)
        {
            [self addEvent];

        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [eventsArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    Routine *tempRoutine = (Routine *)[eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = tempRoutine.name;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

         // Delete the managed object at the given index path.
         NSManagedObject *eventToDelete = [eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [managedObjectContext deleteObject:eventToDelete];

         // Update the array and table view.
         [eventsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

         // Commit the change.
         NSError *error = nil;
         if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
             // Handle the error.
         }
     }
 }
```

**EDIT** Added methods for adding events/objects

```
-(void)addEvent
{    
    Routine *routine = (Routine *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    routine.name=entered;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", error);

    [eventsArray addObject:routine];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    [self.routineTableView reloadData];

    NSInteger lastSection = [self.routineTableView numberOfSections] -1;


    [self.routineTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.routineTableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSection]-1 inSection:lastSection] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}
```

And the fetchResultsController's method:

```
- (void)insertNewObject
{
    // Create a new instance of the entity managed by the fetched results controller.
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
    NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
    // Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
    [newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
```

**Update With Full Code**

```
@implementation RoutineTableViewController

@synthesize routineTableView;
@synthesize eventsArray;
@synthesize entered;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize fetchedResultsController=__fetchedResultsController;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(CurlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    }

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    [self setEventsArray:mutableFetchResults];
    [mutableFetchResults release];
    [request release];

    UIBarButtonItem * addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showPrompt)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:addButton];
    [addButton release];

    UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(toggleEdit)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;
    [editButton release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.eventsArray = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

-(void)toggleEdit
{
    [self.routineTableView setEditing: !self.routineTableView.editing animated:YES];

    if (self.routineTableView.editing)
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
    else
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [__fetchedResultsController release];
    [managedObjectContext release];
    [eventsArray release];
    [entered release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Add an event

-(void)addEvent
{    
    Routine *routine = (Routine *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    routine.name=entered;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", error);

    [eventsArray addObject:routine];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    //[self.routineTableView reloadData];

    NSInteger lastSection = [self.routineTableView numberOfSections] -1;


    [self.routineTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.routineTableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSection]-1 inSection:lastSection] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}
/*
- (void)insertNewObject
{
    // Create a new instance of the entity managed by the fetched results controller.
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
    NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
    // Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
    [newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
         */
/*
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
*/

-(void)showPrompt
{
    AlertPrompt *prompt = [AlertPrompt alloc];
    prompt = [prompt initWithTitle:@"Add Workout Day" message:@"\n \n Please enter title for workout day" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" okButtonTitle:@"Add"];
    [prompt show];
    [prompt release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
    {
        entered = [(AlertPrompt *)alertView enteredText];

        if(eventsArray && entered)
        {
            [self addEvent];

        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    Routine *tempRoutine = (Routine *)[eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = tempRoutine.name;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

         // Delete the managed object for the given index path
         NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
         [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

         // Update the array and table view.
         [eventsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

         // Commit the change.
         NSError *error = nil;
         if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
             // Handle the error.
         }
     }
 }

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"name"] description];
}

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];
     */
}

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (__fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return __fetchedResultsController;
    }

    /*
     Set up the fetched results controller.
     */
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return __fetchedResultsController;
}    

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller delegate

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.routineTableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.routineTableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.routineTableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.routineTableView;

    switch(type)
    {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.routineTableView endUpdates];
}

/*
 // Implementing the above methods to update the table view in response to individual changes may have performance implications if a large number of changes are made simultaneously. If this proves to be an issue, you can instead just implement controllerDidChangeContent: which notifies the delegate that all section and object changes have been processed. 

 - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
 {
 // In the simplest, most efficient, case, reload the table view.
 [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
 */

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, all you would do would be to move your current fetch into the fetched result controllers setup method. Then you would use the fetched results controller `fetchObjects` property (which is an array) exactly as you currently use `eventsArray`.

Look at a Core Data using Navigation based project template in Xcode. It should have a tableview controller configured with a fetched results controller.

Comment: ok, so i got all the code set for the fetchresultscontroller.  one question though, i posted the two methods above.  I currently use `addEvent` to add new cell to my table, but I think fetched result has their own method called `insertNewObject`.  I think I need to somehow merge these two events, can you help me do so?

Comment: @Faisal - You'll want to implement the `-controller: didChangeObject:atIndexPath: forChangeType:newIndexPath:` delegate method and have it handle the `NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert` case.  Apple should supply boilerplate code for this in a new Core Data template application, or Jeff LaMarche has some here: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/01/navigation-based-core-data-application.html .  When you create a new NSManagedObject, this method will be triggered, causing your table view to be updated.

Comment: Thanks Brad, as I said earlier, I have already got all the code relating to the FetchedResultsController from the Xcode Template.  My question now is the view is crashing when I open the view controller.  I think there is some problem with having both my `addEvent` and `insertNewObject` methods which I posted above.

Comment: You could actually use either method as they actually accomplish the same thing. Just remove the `reloadTable` from addEvent. Brad Larson is correct that you need to add the FetchedResultsController code to the tableview controller such that when you do add or insert a new managed object, the tableview controller will update the tableview. Again, the template code should show you how that is done.

Comment: Thanks TechZen and Brad.  I just updated question with my current code.  I think I have all the right FetchedResultsController code set up but I need to figure out how to get rid of eventsArray entirely.  What do I replace it with or use in its place?

Comment: Oh ok, I think I just use fetchObjects Array in place of eventsArray.